# Eclipse RCP: How to listen to CheckboxTableViewer selection in other view

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have an Eclipse RCP with a view whose Control is a CheckboxTableViewer.

I'd like to use the WorkbenchPage's SelectionService (for reasons of loose coupling) to react to check/uncheck actions within the view in an editor.

So I do `getSite().setSelectionProvider(myTableViewer);` in the view's `createPartControl()` method.

Also, I create a listener field in the editor:

```
private ISelectionListener mylistener = new ISelectionListener() {
    public void selectionChanged(IWorkbenchPart sourcepart, ISelection selection) {
        System.out.println(((IStructuredSelection) selection).size());
    }
};
```

Unfortunately, I only get the number of **rows** that are selected printed out in the console, not the number of checked elements. I'm trying to pass `myTableViewer.getCheckedElements()` to the `SelectionProvider` somehow, but cannot find an access point :(.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write your own implementation of `ISelectionProvider` which returns the checked elements instead of using the default provider implemented by `TableViewer` which returns the selected elements.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean my class should implement `ISelectionProvider`, and in `getSelection()` I should return the `getCheckedElements()`? I guess I'd have to wrap the checked elements in an `ISelection`?

Comment: Yes something like that.